# How can I copy the screen of MKMapView in a UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uiimage

I have a screen on my map in MKMapView. How can copy this screen to a image and use it like a simple UIImageView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this may work;

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(MKMapView.bounds.size, MKMapView.opaque, 0.0);
[MKMapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Wow.. This work.. And was less than 2 minutes, this is a world record :) Thanks.

Comment: @Rodrigo: This is the same technique you would use to capture any other view to an image.